# How to pass parameter from thunk to extraReducers?

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

I know `extraReducers` can receive payload data, but can it receive patameter directly from thunk method?

Normally I have this in extraReducers:

```js
.addCase(loginEmail.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
    state.authnRes = payload
})
```

But I would get data from `thunk` itself, how can I pass it?

```js
export const logout = createAsyncThunk(`${namespace}/logout`, async () => {
    const { data } = await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'logout',
        headers: { crossDomain: true },
    })
    return data
})
```

Answer (score 3):

By returning it - your `return data` already does it.

Whatever you `return` from the thunk will end up as `action.payload` in that reducer.